# How to input text into textfield with Selenium and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, selenium, automation, nokogiri

I'm using Selenium Webdriver, Chromedriver, and Nokogiri. I've written a script to go to Google.com and parse the page:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "nokogiri"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser.get "https://google.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.page_source)
```

Now, how can I input text into the searchbar with my ruby script? The searchbar has an id of `#lst-ib`.

Comment: Selenium provides plenty of ways to locate HTML part of a page already. By using Nokogiri, you can locate the same, but you can't interact with the found element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided here [Link](https://gist.github.com/kenrett/7553278#forms) you can do something like:

```
input = wait.until {
    element = browser.find_element(:id, "lst-ib")
    element if element.displayed?
}
input.send_keys("Input")
```